# Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, shift

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':[1,3,3,1,2,3,2,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
print df


         col1  
    0     1          
    1     3          
    2     3          
    3     1          
    4     2          
    5     3          
    6     2          
    7     2
```

I have the following Pandas DataFrame and I want to create another column that compares the previous row of col1 to see if they are equal.  What would be the best way to do this?  It would be like the following DataFrame.  Thanks

```
    col1  match  
0     1   False     
1     3   False     
2     3   True     
3     1   False     
4     2   False     
5     3   False     
6     2   False     
7     2   True
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())
print (df)
   col1  match
0     1  False
1     3  False
2     3   True
3     1  False
4     2  False
5     3  False
6     2  False
7     2   True
```

Or instead `eq` use `==`, but it is a bit slowier in large DataFrame:

```
df['match'] = df.col1 == df.col1.shift()
print (df)
   col1  match
0     1  False
1     3  False
2     3   True
3     1  False
4     2  False
5     3  False
6     2  False
7     2   True
```

**Timings**:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':[1,3,3,1,2,3,2,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
print (df)
#[80000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

df['match'] = df.col1 == df.col1.shift()
df['match1'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())
print (df)

In [208]: %timeit df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())
The slowest run took 4.83 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 933 µs per loop

In [209]: %timeit df.col1 == df.col1.shift()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
```

Comment: You could do `df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: `==` should not be any slower than using `eq` in general (I get the opposite result to you when I test them, for example).

Comment: @ajcr - Thank you for comment. I test it under windows more times and if compare with scalar, timings are same, but if compare 2 Series, `eq`, `ne`, `lt`... was faster as `==`, `!=`, `>` in larger df. What was your timings in larger `df`?

Comment: What an amazing approach! So the `shift` default is to shift down I see. And why does the pandas documentation on `.eq` contains no example that actually used `.eq`? Weird. But I guess it works the same as `==`, except for computing time.

Comment: @jezrael may I know how we can handle if we have null values in between.

Comment: This is great! I recently transitioned to python from R.. How can you do this but by a group? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mar355 - Use `df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.groupby('id').col1.shift())`

Comment: @jezrael Thank so much. Just so it is easier for me to understand. can you do it using df.col1 == df.col1.shift() instead. I find this code easier to grasp. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

1) ***pandas approach:*** Use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['match'] = df['col1'].diff().eq(0)
```

---

2) ***numpy approach:*** Use [`np.ediff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html).

```
df['match'] = np.ediff1d(df['col1'].values, to_begin=np.NaN) == 0
```

Both produce:

[image]

***Timings:*** (for the same `DF` used by @jezrael)

```
%timeit df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())
1000 loops, best of 3: 731 µs per loop

%timeit df['col1'].diff().eq(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 405 µs per loop
```

Comment: I tried both the pandas and numpy  method and it did not work for strings. The pandas resulted in a  `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` and `cannot convert 'to_begin' to array with dtype 'dtype('O')' as required for input ary` respectively.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a NumPy arrays based approach using [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) that lets us use the views into the input array for efficiency purposes -

```
def comp_prev(a):
    return np.concatenate(([False],a[1:] == a[:-1]))

df['match'] = comp_prev(df.col1.values)
```

Sample run -

```
In [48]: df['match'] = comp_prev(df.col1.values)

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
   col1  match
0     1  False
1     3  False
2     3   True
3     1  False
4     2  False
5     3  False
6     2  False
7     2   True
```

Runtime test -

```
In [56]: data={'col1':[1,3,3,1,2,3,2,2]}
    ...: df0=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
    ...: 

#@jezrael's soln1
In [57]: df = pd.concat([df0]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [58]: %timeit df['match'] = df.col1 == df.col1.shift() 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop

#@jezrael's soln2
In [59]: df = pd.concat([df0]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [60]: %timeit df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

#@Nickil Maveli's soln1   
In [61]: df = pd.concat([df0]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [64]: %timeit df['match'] = df['col1'].diff().eq(0) 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop

#@Nickil Maveli's soln2
In [65]: df = pd.concat([df0]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [66]: %timeit df['match'] = np.ediff1d(df['col1'].values, to_begin=np.NaN) == 0
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop

# Posted approach in this post
In [67]: df = pd.concat([df0]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [68]: %timeit df['match'] = comp_prev(df.col1.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 376 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised no one mentioned *rolling* method here. *rolling* can be easily used to verify if the n-previous values are all the same or to perform any custom operations. This is certainly not as fast as using diff or shift but it can be easily adapted for larger windows:

```
df['match'] = df['col1'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) != len(x),raw= True).replace({0 : False, 1: True})
```