# Compare strings with the previous row and calculate the similarity Pandas

Tags: string, pandas, data-cleaning

Is there any way we can use Pandas to calculate the string similarity with the previous rows in the column?

> Row 1: Businesses Pte Ltd
>
> Row 2: Business Pvt Ltd
>
> Row 3: Global Pvt Ltd

It will compare the Row 1 and Row 2, come up with a percentage of similarity. If it is about 90%, replace Row 2 with Row 1 values and so on.

Result

> Row 1: Businesses Pte Ltd
>
> Row 2: Businesses Pte Ltd
>
> Row 3: Global Pvt Ltd

Comment: Can you provide a definition for "percentage of similarity"?

Comment: Can be based on the number of chars, how many chars are different from the previous row..

Comment: That's interesting. I'm afraid SO isn't the best place to design the *logic* for you (but see links in @Matthew's answer for ideas). You will find many people here who are willing to take your logic and transfer it to code in an efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly tricky problem. Presumably you sorted the rows alphabetically first - but what happens if the typo is in the 1st letter? "Businesses Pte Ltd" is a long way from "Vusinesses Pte Ltd".

Still - to solve your problem you want to combine these two solutions:

[Find the similarity percent between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings)

[Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

It should get you something workable.