# Compare current dataframe values to aggregate values from previous timesteps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas time series indexed at 15 minute intervals which are timestamps. At each interval, I have multiple columns `a`, `b` and `c`.

```
| index   | a | b | c |
| 9:00 am | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 9:15 am | 2 | 2 | 4 |
...
```

I need to compare the average the value of `a` at the same time 1, 2, 3 and 4 weeks back to the current timestep. So if my current time is 9:15 am, I need to find the average of `a` at 9:15 am from the previous week, 2 weeks, 3 and 4 weeks back.

Obviously this cannot be calculated on the first 4 weeks of the dataset, because there is not enough history. I'm stuck on how to think about shifting the data frame to the past to get those values to aggregate and then compare to the future.

There is some similarity to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe) but there the index is not a timeseries, and the comparison is a bit simpler.

Comment: What is the dtype of the index?

Comment: @CharlesLandau timestamp, pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

Comment: Is it ok if when you run out of history the output is NaN? (Because that's pretty much what has to happen I think)

Comment: @CharlesLandau yes

Answer (score 2):

Here I do it with days instead of weeks. I start with making dummy data based on your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
d = [
    {"ts":pd.Timestamp(year=2017, month=1, day=1, hour=12,
                 minute=0, second=0) + pd.Timedelta(x*15, unit="s"),
    "a": random.randint(2, 5),
    "b": random.randint(2, 5),
    "c": random.randint(2, 5),} for x in range(0, 30000)
]
dft = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index("ts")
```

I define a handler function that tries to get a value exactly 0, 1, 2, and 3 days from the row. Since I'll get a key error for the first 4 days there's a try-except with `np.NaN`. Note the `Timedelta(unit=)` kwarg. You can change that to get this effect for other units - I think this would be less error-prone than tweaking the call to `range`.

```
def handler(row):
  try: 
    m = np.mean([dft.loc[row.name-pd.Timedelta(x, unit="d")][0] for x in range(4)])
  except KeyError as e:
    return np.NaN
  return m
```

Finally, use `apply`.

```
dft.apply(handler, axis=1)
```

It's fairly slow, so I'll try to think of a faster way but for now I think this is it.