# Python 3 Pandas Dataframe - Implementing a simple shift() using stock data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've looked at a few different solutions on StackOverflow here, but I haven't been able to successfully implement one of them in my application. Mostly because I'm not entirely sure what each solution is doing, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have a simple script that collects daily stock data using DataReader, resamples that data to weekly data, and then I'm trying to see if there's been a gap down in price from the previous week's closing price to this week's opening price.

My code looks like this, which anyone should be able to implement:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Inputs for stock data
stocks = ['AAPL']
ex = 'yahoo'
start = datetime(2018, 1, 2)
end = datetime(2019, 7, 2)

# Now, it'll get the daily stock data for each stock, and convert it to weekly data
for i in stocks:
    a = web.DataReader(i, ex, start, end)

    output = a.resample('W').agg({'Open': 'first', 
                               'High': 'max',
                               'Low': 'min',
                               'Close': 'last',
                               'Volume': 'sum'})
    output.index=output.index+pd.DateOffset(days=-6) # -6 Makes it Monday as the start of the week
    print(output)

    # Now, to iterate over each row, and print each time theres a gap
    for index, row in output.iterrows():
        currentopen = row['Open']
        prevclose = row['Close'].shift(1)
        if currentopen > prevclose:
            print('The current open gapped up from last weeks close.')
        elif currentopen < prevclose:
            print('Houston we have a gap down!')
```

So the current row in the "for" loop represents the current week, and I'm trying to get the "Close" price from the previous row using .shift(). Currently I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

...which I know I'm using the shift wrong in this case. A couple of the solutions I found were below:

[get previous row's value and calculate new column pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081878/get-previous-rows-value-and-calculate-new-column-pandas-python)

[Is there a way in Pandas to use previous row value in dataframe.apply when previous value is also calculated in the apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ)

[Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

...but I'm not sure what I'm reading with those, and how one of them might apply to my app. I'm hoping a more skilled programmer can point me in the right direction with a bit of an explanation so I can learn. Thanks!

Comment: you can use variable to keep value from previous row which you get in `for` loop

Comment: you could create new column with shifted data and then you will have both values in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but I see two methods:

First: use variable to keep value from previous loop in `for`

```
prevclose = None

for index, row in output.iterrows():
    currentopen = row['Open']

    if prevclose:
        if currentopen > prevclose:
            print('The current open gapped up from last weeks close.')
        elif currentopen < prevclose:
            print('Houston we have a gap down!')

    prevclose = row['Close']
```

Second: create column with shifted data to have both values in the same row

```
outer['prevClose'] = outer['Close'].shift()

for index, row in output.iterrows():
    currentopen = row['Open']
    prevclose = row['prevClose']

    if prevclose:
        if currentopen > prevclose:
            print('The current open gapped up from last weeks close.')
        elif currentopen < prevclose:
            print('Houston we have a gap down!')
```

Comment: First solution worked awesome, and I think I'll use that one for this basic script. Thank you for helping me out!