# Transforming pandas dataframe column to networkx graph with source and target

Tags: python, dataframe, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I have a DataFrame in pandas with information about people location in time. It is about 300+ million rows.

Here is the sample where each Name is assigned to a unique `index` by `group.by` and sorted by `Name` and `Year`:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'Name': 'John', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Orange county'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'New York'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2020, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2020, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2020, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2021, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2021, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2021, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2022, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'NewYork'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2022, 'Address':'NewYork'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df['Author_Grouped_Index'] = df.groupby(['Name']).ngroup()
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Year'], ascending=[False, True])
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| Index | Name  | Year | Address       | Name_Grouped_Index   |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 5     | Steve | 2018 | Canada        | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 15    | Steve | 2018 | NewYork       | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 16    | Steve | 2018 | California    | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 6     | Steve | 2019 | Canada        | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 7     | Steve | 2019 | Canada        | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 8     | Steve | 2020 | California    | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 9     | Steve | 2020 | Canada        | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 13    | Steve | 2021 | California    | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 14    | Steve | 2022 | California    | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 17    | Steve | 2022 | NewYork       | 1                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 0     | John  | 2018 | Beverly hills | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 1     | John  | 2018 | Beverly hills | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 2     | John  | 2019 | Beverly hills | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 3     | John  | 2019 | Orange county | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 4     | John  | 2019 | New York      | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 10    | John  | 2020 | Canada        | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 11    | John  | 2021 | Canada        | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
| 12    | John  | 2021 | Beverly hills | 0                    |
+-------+-------+------+---------------+----------------------+
```

I want to get the **network graph matrix** (adjacency matrix) where to see the total of changes between Addresses. In other words, for example, how many times people moved from “Canada” to “California” in 2018.

**Ideal Outputs:**

**1)** A direct graph from the Address column. Technically converting the Address column into two columns "Source" & "Target" where the "Target" value is the "Source" for the next row. Preferably counting the pairs in another column "Weight" instead of pairs being repeated.

```
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| Source     | Target     | Year | Weight |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| Canada     | NewYork    | 2018 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| NewYork    | California | 2018 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| California | Canada     | 2019 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| Canada     | Canada     | 2019 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| Canada     | California | 2020 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| California | Canada     | 2020 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| Canada     | California | 2021 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| California | California | 2022 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
| California | NewYork    | 2022 |        |
+------------+------------+------+--------+
```

OR

**2)** A matrix to illustrate the total changes between addresses.

```
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| From \ To     | Canada | NewYork | California | Beverly hills | Orange county |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Canada        | 2      | 2       | 2          | 2             | 0             |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| NewYork       | 1      | 0       | 1          | 0             | 0             |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| California    | 2      | 1       | 1          | 0             | 0             |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Beverly hills | 0      | 0       | 0          | 2             | 1             |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Orange county | 0      | 1       | 0          | 0             | 0             |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the prettiest code but at least you can follow each step. I've gone for the second option because you can easily make your graph from this connections matrix. Do you need help with making the networkx graph?
The rows and columns of the matrix are : ['Beverly hills', 'Orange county', 'New York', 'Canada', 'California', 'NewYork']
You've spelled newyork differently for each person so it comes up twice.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'Name': 'John', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Orange county'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'New York'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2019, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2020, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2020, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2020, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2021, 'Address':'Canada'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Year':2021, 'Address':'Beverly hills'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2021, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2022, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'NewYork'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2018, 'Address':'California'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Year':2022, 'Address':'NewYork'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df['Author_Grouped_Index'] = df.groupby(['Name']).ngroup()
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Year'], ascending=[False, True])

print (df)
dictionary_ = {} # where each person went
places = [] # all of the places
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Author_Grouped_Index'] not in dictionary_:
        dictionary_[row['Author_Grouped_Index']] = []
        dictionary_[row['Author_Grouped_Index']].append(row["Address"])
    else:
        dictionary_[row['Author_Grouped_Index']].append(row["Address"])
    if row["Address"] not in places:
        places.append(row["Address"])


print (dictionary_)

new_dictionary = {} #number of times each place visited
for key, value in dictionary_.items():
    for x in range(len(value)-1):
        move = value[x] + "-" + value[x+1]
        if not move in new_dictionary:
            new_dictionary[move] = 1
        else:
            new_dictionary[move] += 1

print (new_dictionary)
print (places)
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros((len(places),len(places)), dtype=int)
for x, place in enumerate(places):
    for y, place_2 in enumerate(places):

        move_2 = (place + "-" + place_2)
        try:
            array[x,y] = (new_dictionary[move_2])
        except:
            array[x,y] = 0

print (array)
```

Comment: For the last part of the code starting from "array = np.zero" I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". The error is pointing an arrow (^) to the quotation (:) part of this line: "for x, place in enumerate(places):"
Will appreciate your advice so I can run the code.

Comment: Fixed. Do you need help with plotting the graph in networkx from the numpy array?

Comment: Thanks it worked! It would be perfect if you share the graph plotting in networkx as well!

Comment: Ask a new question with what you are looking to achieve please

Comment: This code will be flawless and I can accept it as an answer if it gives the associated "Year" for each source & target pair. The pairs are generated from second part of the code "new_dictionary" but is it yet possible to have the "Year" for them?

Comment: I have made a new question regarding plotting the resulted NumPy Array in this solution with networkx. Please find the question from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61325124/2739921