# Creating a new column but creates copy of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to check the value of the row above and see it it is the same as the current row. I found a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe): `df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())` such that `col1` is what you are comparing.

However, when I tried it, I received a `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.` warning. My `col1` is a string. I know you can suppress warnings but how would I check the same row above and make sure that I am not creating a copy of the dataframe? Even with the warning I do get my desired output, but was curious if there exists a better way.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d'],
       'week':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','week'])
df['check_condition'] = 1
while sum(df.check_condition) != 0:
    for week in df.week:
        wk = df.loc[df.week == week]
        wk['match'] = wk.col1.eq(wk.col1.shift()) # <-- where the warning occurs
        # fix the repetitive value...which I have not done yet
        # for now just exit out of the while loop
        df.loc[df.week == week,'check_condition'] = 0
```

Comment: If `df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift())` gives you a warning, then `df` is a copy of some bigger dataframe. And no, you may not ignore that warning, the assignment may or may not be successful.

Comment: Updated the question once I did a little more research. Also I was referring to suppress warnings instead of ignore warnings.

Comment: Related: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas). Always post the actual name of the error/exception. Then you can search other questions and answers for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ignore a pandas `SettingWithCopyWarning`!
It's 100% telling you that your code is not going to work as intended, if at all. Stop, investigate and fix it. (It's not an ignoreable thing you can filter out, like a pandas FutureWarning nagging about deprecation.)

Multiple issues with your code:

- You're trying to iterate over a dataframe (but not with `groupby()`), take slices of it (in the subdataframe `wk`, which yes is a copy of a slice)...
- then assign to the (nonexistent) new column `wk['match']`. This is bad, you shouldn't do this. (You could initialize `df['match'] = np.nan`, but it'd still be wrong to try to assign to the copy in `wk`)...
- `SettingWithCopyWarning` is being triggered when you try to assign to `wk['match']`. It's telling you `wk` is a copy of a slice from dataframe `df`, not `df` itself. Hence like it tells you: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.` That assignment would only get thrown away every time `wk` gets overwritten by your loop, so even if you could force it to work on `wk` it would be wrong. That's why `SettingWithCopyWarning` is a code smell you shouldn't be making a copy of a slice of df in the first place.
- Later on, you also try to assign to column `df['check_condition']` while iterating over the df, that's also bad.

Solution:

```
df['check_condition'] = df['col1'].eq(df['col1'].shift()).astype(int)

df
  col1  week  check_condition
0    a     1                0
1    a     1                1
2    a     1                1
3    b     1                0
4    b     1                1
5    c     2                0
6    c     2                1
7    c     2                1
8    d     2                0
9    d     2                1
```

More generally, for more complicated code where you want to iterate over each group of dataframe according to some grouping criteria, you'd use use [`groupby()` and *split-apply-combine*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) instead.

- you're grouping by `wk.col1.eq(wk.col1.shift())`, i.e. rows where `col1` value doesn't change from the preceding row
- and you want to set `check_condition` to 0 on those rows
- and 1 on rows where  `col1` value did change from the preceding row

But in this simpler case you can skip `groupby()` and do a direct assignment.