# Comparing previous row values of every column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe).

I have a dataframe with an ID column and a counter column for this idea which looks like this:

```
ID counter valueA   valueB
A   1       10        1
A   2       10        1
A   3       5         1
B   1       1         2
B   2       1         3
B   3       2         4
B   4       3         4
...
```

How can i count the row changes per column with a 1 in the dataframe, so that the dataframe looks like:

```
ID counter valueA   valueB
A   1       0         0
A   2       0         0
A   3       1         0
B   1       0         0
B   2       0         1
B   3       1         1
B   4       1         1
...
```

So that everytime a value change in the columns (only if it is the same ID, the counter should not be marked)  I got a marker with 1. Note that I have more value columns, this two are only an example.

Comment: Is possible add more data, for test, 2-3 new rows in same group B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'counter': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'valueA': [10, 10, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3], 'valueB': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]})
```

print (df)

---

```
c = ['valueA','valueB']
df[c] = df[c].ne(df[c].groupby(df['ID']).shift().bfill()).astype(int)
print (df)
  ID  counter  valueA  valueB
0  A        1       0       0
1  A        2       0       0
2  A        3       1       0
3  B        1       0       0
4  B        2       0       1
5  B        3       1       1
6  B        4       1       0
```

For counter per groups I try this solution, but still different output:

```
df[c] = df[c].ne(df[c].groupby(df['ID']).shift().bfill()).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()
print (df)
  ID  counter  valueA  valueB
0  A        1       0       0
1  A        2       0       0
2  A        3       1       0
3  B        1       0       0
4  B        2       0       1
5  B        3       1       2
6  B        4       2       2
```

Note: For a success the newest pandas version should be installed

Comment: @PV8 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @PV8 - Maybe it is reason, tested in `pandas 1.1.1`

Comment: for testdata its working, I will try to find the error in my data

Comment: @PV8 - Test if no duplicated columns names.