# sequence of pattern in last 3 values in column pandas + python

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in finding the sequence pattern in the column,
example

```
colour --- match
blue    no match
orange  no match
orange  no match
blue    no match
orange  no match
orange  no match
orange  **match**
```

In the above dataframe, we have 2 columns colour and match. I need to find the sequence  in the Column "Color" it should find last 3 value(blue, orange, orange , orange(current cell)) in the column and if it match then need to update the next column match. I am looking this code to work in python code.

Comment: Might be helpful. [Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` for that purpose: `df["new_col"] = df.col.eq(df.col.shift(1)) & df.col.eq(df.col.shift(2))` to create a boolean Series of values when one in `col` equals the 2 preceding ones !

output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
Name: test, dtype: bool
```

**Edit:** if you want to convert back to "mismatched"/"matched" values you can simply add this

`df["col"] = np.where(df["col"] == False, "mismatched", "matched")`

Comment: but i want the cod to find in this format exactly ( current cell (orange) previous cell should be "orange" +"orange" + "blue" then it should type " matched" else not matched

Comment: it is giving error s is not defined, and also could you please help in getting in same pattern,   ( current cell (orange) previous cell should be "orange" +"orange" + "blue" )

Comment: it worked, real saved my time. Thanks for your valuable inputs Luc Bertin

Comment: if there is new data available/written in the excel file, how to make the python to run continues and check for  update in excel file and run the above code ?