# Selecting a row based on conditions on .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to select a row based on a certain condition from a .csv file.

[image]

As you can see in the image. I have a .csv file containing that table. At the last row the "raw_flow_rate" and "avg_flow_rate" are same. And I am selecting that row with this line of code.

`select_data = New_data[New_data["raw_flow_rate"] == New_data["avg_flow_rate"]]`

And it works perfectly. But my target is to select the previous row of the selected one. Index number 4 in this case. I have tried the ID column to simply select the previous row based on (ID-1) operation.

```
storeID = select_data["ID"] - 1
final_data = New_data[New16_data["ID"] == storeID]
```

But this gives the error `can only compare identically-labeled series objects`

Is there any simple way to select the previous row from the one which met the condition? I'm using Pandas to handle the .csv files. The files are quite big, so a simpler method is preferable. Thanks

Comment: Will you please show a sample of the actual CSV file, for copy/pasting?

Comment: Sure, there you go

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UGOGW4Vx6YuhJlgLe81GJ7TsDR2GEDfW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you tried using `.shift()`?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399538/comparing-previous-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `New_data["raw_flow_rate"] == New_data["avg_flow_rate"]` is a mask, you can shift the mask up by one:

```
select_data = New_data[(New_data["raw_flow_rate"] == New_data["avg_flow_rate"]).shift(-1).fillna(False)]
```